# Bootstrap как сделать текст по центру?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте уважаемые читатели.
Есть следующий текст

```
<div id="content_center" class="row " style="padding-top: 98px;">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-centered  ">

    <p id="center_text_first">Товарищи! постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности<br>
        позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке направлений прогрессивного развития.<br>
        С другой стороны дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности требуют определения и <br> уточнения
        дальнейших направлений развития.</p>
    <p id="center_text_second">Товарищи! новая модель организационной деятельности способствует подготовки
        и реализации <br> позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Значимость этих проблем <br>
        настолько очевидна, что новая модель организационной деятельности влечет за собой процесс <br> внедрения и
        модернизации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. <br> Задача организации, в
        особенности же постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей <br> активности обеспечивает широкому кругу
        (специалистов) участие в формировании дальнейших <br> направлений развития. Разнообразный и богатый опыт
        укрепление и развитие структуры требуют <br> определения и уточнения модели развития.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success center-block" style="align-content: center">Кнопка</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Как можно поставить текст по центру дива? class="text-center" не помогает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Текст форматируется
Можно ли сделать так, только по середине дива?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для начала посмотрите в отладчике, почему не работает class="text-center"  - узнайте, что перебивает его стили. ибо центровка должна работает при применении стиля `text-align: center` к самому тексту

Comment: извините, возможно я не так выразился, text-center отрабатывает - первый скриншот. Нужно что бы текст, как на 2 скриншоте был в центре дива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поубирайте `<br>` из `<p>`, добавьте css class .text-justify и сделайте нормальную bootstrap разметку

```css
.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-sm-8 text-justify"> 
  <p id="center_text_first">Товарищи! постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельностипозволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке направлений прогрессивного развития.
        С другой стороны дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности требуют определения и уточнения дальнейших направлений развития.</p>
    <p id="center_text_second">Товарищи! новая модель организационной деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Значимость этих проблем       настолько очевидна, что новая модель организационной деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и  модернизации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Задача организации, в особенности же постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании дальнейших правлений развития. Разнообразный и богатый опыт
        укрепление и развитие структуры требуют определения и уточнения модели развития.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success center-block" style="align-content: center">Кнопка</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое - все заработало!